# Adjusting div width and height after rotated

Tags: height, width, css, rotation

If I have these rules:

```
width:50px;
height:100px;
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
```

and then an event changes the transform to:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg)
```

logically, shouldn't that automatically exchange the width and the height? I need the rotate to switch width and height for accurate position detection.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30157405/133327

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like the transform is applied after everything else, so the width and height aren't updated. The best solution I can think of is to calculate the rotated dimensions yourself, using the rotation matrix:

```
[ cos X     -sin X ] [ width  ]
[ sin X      cos X ] [ height ]
```

It's straightforward to translate this into JavaScript. You need to rotate all four corners (0,0) (w,0) (0,h) (w,h) and then the rotated dimensions are the width and height of the rotated bounding rectangle.

```
var angle = angle_in_degrees * Math.PI / 180,
    sin   = Math.sin(angle),
    cos   = Math.cos(angle);

// (0,0) stays as (0, 0)

// (w,0) rotation
var x1 = cos * width,
    y1 = sin * width;

// (0,h) rotation
var x2 = -sin * height,
    y2 = cos * height;

// (w,h) rotation
var x3 = cos * width - sin * height,
    y3 = sin * width + cos * height;

var minX = Math.min(0, x1, x2, x3),
    maxX = Math.max(0, x1, x2, x3),
    minY = Math.min(0, y1, y2, y3),
    maxY = Math.max(0, y1, y2, y3);

var rotatedWidth  = maxX - minX,
    rotatedHeight = maxY - minY;
```

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @T4NK3R, and this even though I studied transformation matrices to exhaustion in graduate school. Not that the above is "hard". But WHY!? Shouldn't this be obviously handled by the original transform?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the most elegant JavaScript solution, that I have achieved.

```
// suppose, we know width, height and rotation angle (deg)
var width, height, angle;

var rad = angle * Math.PI / 180,
    sin = Math.sin(rad),
    cos = Math.cos(rad);

var newWidth  = Math.abs(width * cos) + Math.abs(height * sin),
    newHeight = Math.abs(width * sin) + Math.abs(height * cos);
```