# width/height after transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I retrieve the width and height properties after I've applied `transform: rotate(45deg);`?

Like, 11x11 square after rotation becomes 17x17 (Chrome result), but javascript still returns original width/height - 10x10.

How do I get this 17x17?

Comment: i wonder why you're getting 17x17, supposed it's rotated by 45 degrees from 11x11, then new dimensions should be 15x15, or 16x16

Comment: I think Chrome automatically ceils the cosinus result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Even if you rotate something the dimensions of it do not change, so you need a wrapper.
Try wrapping your div with another div element and count the wrappers dimensions:

```
  <style type="text/css">
  #wrap {
    border:1px solid green;
    float:left;
    }

  #box {
    -moz-transform:rotate(120deg);
    border:1px solid red;
    width:11px;
    height:11px;
  }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#box').width());
    alert($('#wrap').width());
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrap">
  <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Redited:** the wrapper solution is not working properly, as the wrapper is not automatically adjusted to the contents of the inner div. Follow the mathematical solution:

```
var rotationAngle;

var x = $('#box').width()*Math.cos(rotationAngle) + $('#box').height()*Math.sin(rotationAngle);
```

Comment: Maybe in Firefox it doesn't change, but Chrome in inspector view shows calculated values. Wrapper is a great solution, but it's expensive.

Comment: @Tom firefox behaves just like you described. first of all we need to keep clear that a rotated box has still the same dimensions. its like, if you rotate a piece of paper on your desk, its dimensions remain the same. thats why you need the wrapper. if you cant affort it you need mathematics to calculate the dimensions you need. the same mathematics, firefox uses internally to calculate wrap's dimensions. please consider my +1 here.

Comment: Yeah, while you posted this, I already made a function to calculate new dimensions. -1 for CSS3/DOM3/HTML5 for not making native functions to retrieve these essential values.

Comment: While hitting away on this, I finally figured out that cos/sin in javascript take radials! Not degrees! I hope I saved someone a little time with this comment ;)

Comment: The mathematical solution is working well for the width, how can I do the same to calculate the height?

Answer (score 75):

Instead of calculating it yourself, you can get this via the `HTMLDOMElement`'s [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect).

This will return an object with the correct `height` and `width`, taking into account the transformation matrix.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5Qgx/).

Comment: @Userpassword Yes, that's how jQuery works. You'd need to use `[0]` or `get(0)` or similar.

Comment: I only got this to work correctly. Yes I know the question is old, but if the question was asked today I beilieve this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is so much simpler. Thank you.

Comment: Agreed with everyone else.  This should be the accept answer versus the other over-engineered/complicated solutions.

Comment: I know this type of comment isn't allowed but I like how @alex put OP's picture to jsfiddle instead of some random image xD

Comment: Be careful - getBoundingClientRect() values are affected by css transitions. If reported values are wrong, check if element has some css transitions applied and disable them.

Comment: @userlond. I also stumbled on this issue when applying a rotation. What worked for me is wrapping the call to getBoundingClientRect() into a window.requestAnimationFrame(). I.e. window.requestAnimationFrame( () => { clientRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect() });

Answer (score 9):

I made a function for this, [`domvertices.js`](https://gist.github.com/abernier/97a5fb8c1bebacd1958e#file-domvertices-js)

It computes the 4 vertices 3d coordinates of **any, deep, `transform`ed, `position`ed DOM element** -- really just any element: see the [DEMO](http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/97a5fb8c1bebacd1958e).

```
a                b
 +--------------+
 |              |
 |      el      |
 |              |
 +--------------+
d                c

var v = domvertices(el);
console.log(v);
{
  a: {x: , y: , z: },
  b: {x: , y: , z: },
  c: {x: , y: , z: },
  d: {x: , y: , z: }
}
```

With those vertices, you can compute anything among: width, height... Eg, in your case:

```
// norm(a,b)
var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v.b.x - v.a.x, 2) + Math.pow(v.b.y - v.a.y, 2));
```

See the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domvertices) for more infos.

--

It is published as a npm module (with no dep), so just install it with:

```
npm install domvertices
```

Cheers.

Comment: Cool! A very nice add would be `width` and `height` (or `w,h`) for those of us who remember math not so good ;) Even as `function`s would be great if you want to avoid the calcs if they are not used.

Comment: @abernier [maybe you are the one who can answer my question (bounty +100)??? Any help is very apreciated...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578101/formular-to-calculate-width-height-relative-to-parent-of-container-with-transl)

Answer (score 4):

In case you're looking for a function to programmatically calculate these values...

```
// return an object with full width/height (including borders), top/bottom coordinates
var getPositionData = function(el){
    return $.extend({ width : el.outerWidth(false), height : el.outerHeight(false) }, el.offset());
};

// get rotated dimensions   
var transformedDimensions = function(el, angle){
    var dimensions = getPositionData(el);
    return { width : dimensions.width + Math.ceil(dimensions.width * Math.cos(angle)), height : dimensions.height + Math.ceil(dimensions.height * Math.cos(angle)) };
}
```

Here's a little something I put up. Probably not the best thing ever, but does the job for me.