# Calculate rotated rectangle size from known bounding box coordinates

Tags: math, geometry, rotation, bounding-box

I read the [Calculate Bounding box coordinates from a rotated rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle) to know how to calculate bounding box coordinates from a rotated rectangle. But in a special case as follow image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UNfD.png]

How to get the rotated rectangle size if had get the bounding box size, coordinates and rotate degree?

I try write code in javascript

```
//assume w=123,h=98,deg=35 and get calculate box size
var deg = 35;
var bw = 156.9661922099485;
var bh = 150.82680201149986;

//calculate w and h
var xMax = bw / 2;
var yMax = bh / 2;
var radian = (deg / 180) * Math.PI;
var cosine = Math.cos(radian);
var sine = Math.sin(radian);
var cx = (xMax * cosine) + (yMax * sine)   / (cosine * cosine + sine * sine);
var cy =  -(-(xMax * sine)  - (yMax * cosine) / (cosine * cosine + sine * sine));
var w = (cx * 2 - bw)*2;
var h = (cy * 2 - bh)*2;
```

But...the answer is not match w and h

Comment: what do you mean by "rectangle size"? if you rotate an object, you will obtain, well, the same object rotated... same lengths, same area ... if you have the result of the rotation and not the original object, just use the coordinates (you say you have them), computing distances between the "corner points" to get the length of each side.

Comment: I'm assuming, with reference to your "Case Image", that you have `bh`, `bw` and `theta`, and you want `w` and `h`?

Comment: I think your Javascript code is nearly correct, but you're off by a few plus/minus signs. See my answer.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30157405/133327

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[image]

## Solution

Given bounding box dimensions `bx` by `by` and `t` being the anticlockwise rotation of rectangle sized `x` by `y`:

```
x = (1/(cos(t)^2-sin(t)^2)) * (  bx * cos(t) - by * sin(t))
y = (1/(cos(t)^2-sin(t)^2)) * (- bx * sin(t) + by * cos(t))
```

## Derivation

Why is this?

First, consider that the length `bx` is cut in two pieces, `a` and `b`, by the corner of the rectangle. Use trigonometry to express `bx` in terms of `x`, `y`, and `theta`:

```
bx = b          + a
bx = x * cos(t) + y * sin(t)            [1]
```

and similarly for `by`:

```
by = c          + d
by = x * sin(t) + y * cos(t)            [2]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq85E.jpg) and [2](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm) can be expressed in matrix form as:

```
[ bx ] = [ cos(t)  sin(t) ] * [ x ]     [3]
[ by ]   [ sin(t)  cos(t) ]   [ y ]
```

Note that the matrix is *nearly* a rotation matrix (but not quite - it's off by a minus sign.)

Left-divide the matrix on both sides, giving:

```
[ x ] = inverse ( [ cos(t)  sin(t) ]    * [ bx ]                        [4]
[ y ]             [ sin(t)  cos(t) ] )    [ by ]
```

The matrix inverse is [easy to evaluate for a 2x2 matrix](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm) and expands to:

```
[ x ] = (1/(cos(t)^2-sin(t)^2)) * [ cos(t) -sin(t) ] * [ bx ]           [5]
[ y ]                             [-sin(t)  cos(t) ]   [ by ]
```

[5] gives the two formulas:

```
x = (1/(cos(t)^2-sin(t)^2)) * (  bx * cos(t) - by * sin(t))             [6]
y = (1/(cos(t)^2-sin(t)^2)) * (- bx * sin(t) + by * cos(t))
```

Easy as pie!

Comment: And this is what five years of university-level mathematics teaches you how to do. :P

Comment: +1: Li-aung Yip: you put me to shame with the amount of time and effort you have put into this answer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Time and effort spent answering questions is proportional to how interesting the question is. This one [nerd sniped](http://xkcd.com/356/) me. ;)

Comment: @Li-aungYip: I want do upvote,but my reputation is not enough.I will redo when I get 15 reputation. :)

Comment: Actually you can accept answers even when you're at 1 rep. Just click the "tick mark" under the voting buttons to accept the answer. Accepting answers gives you 2 reputation points!

Comment: Stupid Question: Does this work with a non-negative T? EG: Will this work with a rotation of 35 degrees? Or 325 degrees (aka -35 degrees)? Thanks!

Comment: @Campbeln: I didn't specify any constraints on `theta` and I've no reason to believe that the sign of `theta` matters. Have you tried  it?

Comment: I'm working with it now, but I just realized my problem differs a bit... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392658/calculate-the-bounding-boxs-x-y-height-and-width-of-a-rotated-element-via-jav I have the X, Y and T (angle of rotation), and I'd like to find BX, BY and the X/Y coords for the top-left corner. The question at the link above is written in JavaScript, but I've referenced the sources for the calcs (including yours here ;) so even if you do not know JS, it should be parse-able for you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, when theta is 45, we get really wrong results due to the division by 0 1/(cos(t)^2-sin(t)^2) what can be done for this?

Comment: @anna.mi for 45º, there is no inverse matrix. See http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html - The Inverse May Not Exist. I would assume that you'd have to  use the affine transformation method mentioned below.

Comment: Got wrong results in C# until I converted the degrees to radians. Then everything was fine.

Comment: To make your answer even more awesome, would you please care to state the formulas the other way round? you see, I need to rotate and crop an image (around a face I detect there) and I have the (x,y) in your terminology, and I need to calculate (bx,by.)...

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need something like [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) to discover point coordinates. And then using standard geometry formulas calculate the size.

Comment: An affine transformation is a very general case of rotation. In this case only simple trigonometry is required. ;)

Comment: Though knowing about affine wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: How would we apply the affine transportation to this particular instance? Could you please provide an example?