# Android Opencv calculate size of rotated image inside rectangle

Tags: android, opencv, math

I want to calculate  rotated image size, Image is inside rectangle. I have rectangle width, height and angle of rotated image. Any one tell me 
how to calculate rotated image size?[image]

Comment: For clarification, you have h, w and theta(as shown in image) of the blue rectangle. And you want to calculate area of blue rectangle? I must be missing something because it is not a question in itself :P

Comment: @PervezAlam I have outer rectangle width, height, now i want to have inner rotated image size.

Comment: h x sin(θ) + w x cos(θ) = bh; 
h x cos(θ) + w x sin(θ) = bw; 
You can solve above two equations for 2 variables h, w, as you said θ is known.

Comment: We can get size of outer rectangle but cant get size of rotated image.

Comment: if you solve the above equations for h, w; it will give you dimension of inner rectangle also. If you see any difficulty, please lemme know.

Comment: Inner rotated image size must be smaller than outer rectangle if we use these formulas?

Comment: Your given formula are giving negative values for width, height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55832/discussion-between-pervez-alam-and-nouman-bhatti).

Comment: @NoumanBhatti Have you seen the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971230/calculate-rotated-rectangle-size-from-known-bounding-box-coordinates

Comment: Yes, I tried with this , i'm not getting smaller values(width, height) than outer bounds. Only for few angles it is working.

Answer (score 0):

So you have width, height and angle means you already got [RotatedRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rotatedrect).

Now using the method

```
Rect RotatedRect::boundingRect();
```

you can easly calculate the bounding box for rotated rect.

for more info see  [RotatedRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rotatedrect).

**Edit:**

As per your comment below  is the way how to find the width and height of rotated rect.

So you know the four corners of rectangle, lets say (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4), now you need to find the transformed point after rotation by the given angle, let it be (xT1,yT1),(xT2,yT2),etc...

where

```
xT = x0+(x-x0)*cos(theta)+(y-y0)*sin(theta)
yT = y0-(x-x0)*sin(theta)+(y-y0)*cos(theta)
```

here (x0,y0) is the center around which you are rotating. and `theta = angle * CV_PI / 180.0`

Using above calculate four transformed points,  finally  calculate the height and width by finding the distance between transformed points.

Comment: I have outer rectangle width, height, now i want to have inner rotated image size.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstand your question, I thought all the data is of rotated rect and you need to find the bounding rect.

Comment: I'm always getting width, height of rotated image greater than outer rectangle. If i'm not wrong my rotated image width, height must be less than outer rectangle.

Comment: I'm now using this formula to get width height after getting all point using you formula. So using this link i'm getting the same width, height i have of outer rectangle.
[10:51:47 AM] Farrakh Javed: http://www.mathopenref.com/coordrectangle.html