# How to get the position of element transformed with css rotate

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, css-transforms

I'm having a problem with getting the position of a div after `rotate` filter is applied to it. I have the position of one end, its height, and the angle by which it is rotated, but after checking what this filter actually does on MDN ("[cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 0]") I still don't know how to crack it.

Example :

[image]

The div I'm interested in is the dashed line. Its styling at that moment was :

`left: 80px; top: 12px; height: 69.5122px; width: 2px; -moz-transform: rotate(-1.21366rad);`

(`top`/`left` describe the position of its beginning.) I'm trying to get the `top`/`left` position of its end.

Comment: after refreshing my mathematics knowledge I've came up with something like this : var x = termin.top + Math.cos(angle) * div.height; var y = div.left + Math.sin(angle) * div.height; Can anyone confirm if that's the proper solution ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per your current Question and your requested confirmation of:

```
var x = termin.top + Math.cos(angle) * div.height;
var y = div.left + Math.sin(angle) * div.height;
```

The solution can be found in this other [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7566192/1195891) for a *different question*, enhanced here:

```
// return an object with full width/height (including borders), top/bottom coordinates
var getPositionData = function(el) {
    return $.extend({
        width: el.outerWidth(false),
        height: el.outerHeight(false)
    }, el.offset());
};

// get rotated dimensions   
var transformedDimensions = function(el, angle) {
    var dimensions = getPositionData(el);
    return {
        width: dimensions.width + Math.ceil(dimensions.width * Math.cos(angle)),
        height: dimensions.height + Math.ceil(dimensions.height * Math.cos(angle))
    };
};
```

Here's an **interactive** jsFiddle that provides **real-time updates** for `getPositionData();` function.
You'll be able to see the `top` and `left` values at the end of the **CSS3 Rotation** process you control.

**Reference:**   [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8d6k/)

**Status Update:** The above jsFiddle works great for **0-90deg** and can be approved upon for all angles and different units such as [**rad, grad, and turn**](http://www.impressivewebs.com/alternative-units-css3-rotate-transforms/).

Answer (score 5):

Try using `element.getBoundingClientRect()`

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect):

> Starting in Gecko 12.0 (Firefox 12.0 / Thunderbird 12.0) , the effect of CSS transforms is
>   considered when computing the element's bounding rectangle.

Comment: Do we know what other browsers take consideration of transforms with `getBoundingClientRect`? Most importantly: at which point IE does? Does it work with IE9?

Comment: @JimboJonny [from my testing](https://jsfiddle.net/hhwrv5ov/) is seems IE9 also takes transforms into consideration (but rounds the results to whole pixels). IE10 works like any other browsers (does not round results).