# Dragging a rotated div simultaneously with an image

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs. One with a border, same size of an image.

- When I have a image (Tweet image, not rotated) it works.
- **When i move the rotated image (clown image), the div moves unwanted (at start drag)**
- **The image is not at the same location.**

How to solve this problem with css / jquery?

```
// putting images on screan
$("#img1").css({"top": "200px", "left": "100px"});
$("#img1").myrotate();
$("#img2").css({"top": "100px", "left": "300px"});
$("#img2").myrotate(); 

// rotating image 2 
rotateMe($("#img2"), 45);
rotateMe(selectedDiv, 45);



// here is the problem
div.draggable({
     drag: function() {
          id = $(this).attr("id").substring(3);    
          var pos = $(this).position();
          $("#" + id).css({"top": pos.top + "px", "left": pos.left + "px"});
     }
});
```

[Fiddle over here](http://jsfiddle.net/begt4/3)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523747/webkit-and-jquery-draggable-jumping maybe this help

Comment: It works a bit.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorns/H2HRh/1/
The border image is not moving anymore.

Comment: Maybe for the image i can calculate the angle and distance like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229040/how-to-get-the-position-of-element-transformed-with-css-rotate