# How can I wrap a container around its css-transformed contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, css-transforms

When I use `scale` or `rotate`, the parent element wraps to the size of the pre-translation dimensions of the element.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hughes/hztmv/)

[image: Transformed image]

Is there any way to wrap the parent container around the bounding box of the transformed element with CSS, or do I need to use Maths to manually position things?

Comment: Please note the browser issues related to webkit-css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question correctly, do you want the parent-wrapper to follow the child or what?

Answer (score 0):

[Based on this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565542/width-height-after-transform) it sounds like you will need to use some math and javascript to change the wrapper.

By using the function in the answer you could then set the wrapper dimensions based on the dimensions you just calculated.