# Get the width and height of rotated object after transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This question is a followup to the question: [width/height after transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565542/width-height-after-transform).

I am posting a new question because that question only solves the width and not the height.
The formula:

```
var x = $('#box').width()*Math.cos(rotationAngle) 
      + $('#box').height()*Math.sin(rotationAngle);
```

works well for the width, what is the equivalent formula to calculate the height?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a guess and you'll probably get it right. This is trivial (especially from the equation that you have), not to mention all over the Internet.

Comment: I have tried switching between the cos and the sin, however it didn't work... I will be happy to hear your answer :)

Comment: Switching the cos and the sin *is* the answer, but I will say that the formula you've been given is missing the necessary Math.abs calls. As I said, it's all over the Internet.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30157405/133327

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the best working formula I have come up with:

```
var h = $(obj).height() * Math.abs(Math.cos(deg)) + $(obj).width() * Math.abs(Math.sin(deg));
var w = $(obj).width() * Math.abs(Math.cos(deg)) + $(obj).height() * Math.abs(Math.sin(deg));
```

Comment: damn angle was in radians and I was putting in degrees lol

Comment: Can you find original height and width from the angle and h & w ? what would be the formula ?

Answer (score 2):

The below code will work out the bounding box for a rotated object in JavaScript.

```js
var obj = document.getElementById("obj"); // Get object
var bx = obj.clientWidth; // Width of rectangle
var by = obj.clientHeight; // Height of rectangle
var t = /[0-9]+/.exec(obj.style.transform)[0] * Math.PI / 180; // Convert to radians

var x = Math.sin(t) * by + Math.cos(t) * bx; // The bounding box width
var y = Math.sin(t) * bx + Math.cos(t) * by; // The bounding box height

document.write(x.toFixed(2), " ", y.toFixed(2)); // The width and height of finished bounding box of item rounded to 2 decimal places
```

```html
<div id="obj" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; transform: rotate(30deg); background: red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @ChiMo will not work if the angle value is negative.
Fixed version:

```js
var obj = document.getElementById("obj"); // Get object
var bx = obj.clientWidth; // Width of rectangle
var by = obj.clientHeight; // Height of rectangle
var t = /[0-9]+/.exec(obj.style.transform)[0] * Math.PI / 180; // Convert to radians
var x = Math.sin(t) * by + Math.cos(t) * bx; // The bounding box width
var y = Math.sin(t) * bx + Math.cos(t) * by; // The bounding box height

document.write(x.toFixed(2), " ", y.toFixed(2)); // The width and height of finished bounding box of item rounded to 2 decimal places

var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"); // Get object
wrapper.style.width = Math.round(x) + 'px';
wrapper.style.height = Math.round(y) + 'px';
```

```css
#obj {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="obj" style="transform: rotate(-30deg)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, your previous question involved a square.  Squares have the same dimensions all the way around.  So, unless there's something funky going on, your height should be exactly the same as your width.

Comment: Yes the original question involved a square, I am asking about rectangle.