# How to calculate angle of rotation to make width fit desired size in perspective mode?

Tags: javascript, css, math, css-transforms, perspective

I am trying to come up with a way to rotate an image in perspective around the Y axis via CSS so that the final visible width equals a desired number of pixels.

For example, I might want to rotate a `300px` image so that, after rotation and perspective is applied, the width of the image is now `240px` (80% of original). By trial and error I know I can set `transform: perspective(300) rotateY(-12.68)` and it puts the top left point at `-240px` (this is using the right side of the image as the origin)

I can't quite figure out how to reverse engineer this so that for any given image width, perspective and desired width I can calculate the necessary rotation.

Eg. For the same `300px` image, I now want it to be a width of `150px` after rotation - what is the calculation required to get the necessary angle?

Here's a playground to give you an idea of what I'm looking for, I've replicated the math done by the perspective and rotation transforms to calculate the final position of the left-most point, but I haven't been able to figure out how to solve for the angle given the matrix math and multiple steps involved.

https://repl.it/@BenSlinger/PerspectiveWidthDemo

```js
const calculateLeftTopPointAfterTransforms = (perspective, rotation, width) => {

  // convert degrees to radians
  const rRad = rotation * (Math.PI / 180);

  // place the camera
  const cameraMatrix = math.matrix([0, 0, -perspective]);

  // get the upper left point of the image based on middle right transform origin
  const leftMostPoint = math.matrix([-width, -width / 2, 0]);

  const rotateYMatrix = math.matrix([
    [Math.cos(-rRad), 0, -Math.sin(-rRad)],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [Math.sin(-rRad), 0, Math.cos(-rRad)],
  ]);

  // apply rotation to point
  const rotatedPoint = math.multiply(rotateYMatrix, leftMostPoint);

  const cameraProjection = math.subtract(rotatedPoint, cameraMatrix);

  const pointInHomogenizedCoords = math.multiply(math.matrix([
    [1, 0, 0 / perspective, 0],
    [0, 1, 0 / perspective, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1 / perspective, 0],
  ]), cameraProjection.resize([4], 1));

  const finalPoint = [
    math.subset(pointInHomogenizedCoords, math.index(0))
    / math.subset(pointInHomogenizedCoords, math.index(3)),
    math.subset(pointInHomogenizedCoords, math.index(1))
    / math.subset(pointInHomogenizedCoords, math.index(3)),
  ];

  return finalPoint;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>


 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
 
  <script type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-class-properties" >
  // GOAL: Given the percentage defined in desiredWidth, calculate the rotation required for the transformed image to fill that space (shown by red background)

// eg: With desiredWidth 80 at perspective 300 and image size 300, rotation needs to be 12.68, putting the left point at 300 * .8 = 240.
// How do I calculate that rotation for any desired width, perspective and image size?


// factor out some styles
const inputStyles = { width: 50 };

const PerspDemo = () => {

  const [desiredWidth, setDesiredWidth] = React.useState(80);
  const [rotation, setRotation] = React.useState(25);
  const [perspective, setPerspective] = React.useState(300);
  const [imageSize, setImageSize] = React.useState(300);
  const [transformedPointPosition, setTPP] = React.useState([0, 0]);

  const boxStyles = { outline: '1px solid red', width: imageSize + 'px', height: imageSize + 'px', margin: '10px', position: 'relative' };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTPP(calculateLeftTopPointAfterTransforms(perspective, rotation, imageSize))
  }, [rotation, perspective]);


  return <div>
    <div>
      <label>Image size</label>
      <input
        style={inputStyles}
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => setImageSize(e.target.value)}
        value={imageSize}
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Desired width after transforms (% of size)</label>
      <input
        style={inputStyles}
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => setDesiredWidth(e.target.value)}
        value={desiredWidth}
      />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Rotation (deg)</label>
      <input
        style={inputStyles}
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => setRotation(e.target.value)}
        value={rotation}
      />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Perspective</label>
      <input
        style={inputStyles}
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => setPerspective(e.target.value)}
        value={perspective}
      />
    </div>



    <div>No transforms:</div>
    <div style={boxStyles}>
      <div>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/${imageSize}/${imageSize}`} />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>With rotation and perspective:</div>
    <div style={boxStyles}>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', position: 'absolute', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flexBasis: 100 - desiredWidth + '%' }} />
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flexGrow: 1 }} />

      </div>
      <div style={{
        transform: `perspective(${perspective}px) rotateY(-${rotation}deg)`,
        transformOrigin: '100% 50% 0'
      }}>
        <img src={`https://picsum.photos/${imageSize}/${imageSize}`} />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>{transformedPointPosition.toString()}</div>
  </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<PerspDemo />, document.getElementById('app'));

  </script>
  
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.0.4/math.min.js"></script>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you know the math rules you can calc the new width and set it with js. Try to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46107713/11368483 maybe you can ask in mathematics specific community

Comment: @red, sorry, my original question must not have been clear enough. I know how to solve for the width, I'm actually trying to solve for the angle so that the resulting image will be a given width. I've edited the question to clarify.

(I tried asking in math.stackexchange.com and it was deemed off-topic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider a different way to find the formula without matrix calculation<sup>1</sup> to obtain the following:

```
R = (p * cos(angle) * D)/(p - (sin(angle) * D))
```

Where `p` is the perspective and `angle` is the angle rotation and `D` is the element width and `R` is the new width we are searching for.

If we have an angle of `-45deg` and a perspective equal to `100px` and an initial width `200px` then the new width will be: `58.58px`

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) right/58.58px 100% no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}

img {
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" style="transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(-45deg)">
</div>
```

If we have an angle of `-30deg` and a perspective equal to `200px` and an initial width `200px` then the new width will be `115.46px`

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) right/115.46px 100% no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}

img {
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" style="transform:perspective(200px) rotateY(-30deg)">
</div>
```

<sup>1</sup> To better understand the formula let's consider the following figure:

[image]

Imagine that we are looking at everything from the top. The red line is our rotated element. The big black dot is our point of view with a distance equal to `p` from the scene (this is our perspective). Since the `transform-origin` is the right, it's logical to have this point at the right. Otherwise, it should at the center.

Now, what we see is the width designed by `R` and `W` is the width we see without perspective. It's clear that with a big perspective we see almost the same without perspective

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

img {
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" style="transform: rotateY(-30deg)">
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" style="transform:perspective(9999px) rotateY(-30deg)">
</div>
```

and with a small perspective we see a small width

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

img {
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" style="transform: rotateY(-30deg)">
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" style="transform:perspective(15px) rotateY(-30deg)">
</div>
```

If we consider the angle noted by `O` in the figure we can write the following formula:

```
tan(O) = R/p
```

and

```
tan(O) = W/(L + p)
```

So we will have `R = p*W /(L + p)` with `W = cos(-angle)*D = cos(angle)*D` and `L = sin(-angle)*D = -sin(angle)*D` which will give us:

```
R = (p * cos(angle) * D)/(p - (sin(angle) * D))
```

---

To find the angle we can transform our formula to be:

```
R*p - R*D*sin(angle) = p*D*cos(angle)
R*p = D*(p*cos(angle) + R*sin(angle))
```

Then like described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322515/695610)<sup>1</sup> we can obtain the following equation:

```
angle = sin-1((R*p)/(D*sqrt(p²+R²))) - tan-1(p/R)
```

If you want a perspective equal to `190px` and R equal to `150px` and `D` equal to `200px` you need a rotation equal to `-15.635deg`

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) right/150px 100% no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}

img {
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" style="transform:perspective(190px) rotateY(-15.635deg)">
</div>
```

<sup>1 Thanks to the https://math.stackexchange.com community that helped me identify the right formula</sup>

Comment: Hi Temani, thanks for the detailed response, but I think you've misunderstood the question. I'm already able to see what the width will be given an angle and perspective, but I'm trying to rearrange that equation so that, given a desired width (R in your example) I can calculate the angle required. So solving for the angle, as opposed to the width. Sorry if that wasn't clear from the original question, I'll edit it to clarify.

Comment: @BenSlinger I know, that's what is missing in my answer as noted at the end. I was able to identify the formula but now need to change it to express angle with the other parametres But we have at least the formula that we can start with

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I didn't realize what you meant by that, sorry! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @BenSlinger I made a first update with a formula to find the angle but in a particular case. I guess it would be difficult to handle all the cases because in some cases it's impossible to find the angle as it's not defined

Comment: thanks so much for your work - I'm not sure how to get this working when perpective doesn't equal image size though, which is generally not going to be the case. I'm also not quite sure how to determine the value of R in your final equation, is R not derived from the angle earlier up?

Comment: @BenSlinger it's not easy to get it working if R is different from perspective because the formula isn't defined in some case. well it's very complicated. I can get more formula for other particular cases but I need to define a relation between R and p. Here I concisder `p=R`, I can also do the same for ``p=sqrt(3)*R` but a generic formula is not easy. By the way, I have find the formula which is the difficult part. Now you need to find the needed math tricks to express the angle based on the other properties. You will have better luck than the matrix calculation

Comment: @BenSlinger in the final formula you have `sin(angle + 45deg)*(D*sqrt(2)) = R`

Comment: Unfortunately separating perspective and image size is a requirement - I don't need a single formula, performing multiple steps is fine, and I thought there might be a way to re-arrange the steps including the matrix transforms to get the angle out.

Comment: @BenSlinger finally I have your formula ;) check the update

Comment: Thankyou, that works! Really appreciate the time you gave me on this!