# Why CSS translateZ is ignored if parent element has a transform of its own?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, perspective

Can anyone explain this behavior?

I have three nested elements: a container `div`, a subcontainer `div` and a "shape/image" `div`. The markup is like below:

```
<html>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="subcontainer">
      <div class="shape"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

When I apply `transform: translateZ()` to the shape, obviously it will only work if one of the parents has some `perspective` applied. It doesn't need to be necessarily the direct parent, it can be the parent's parent `div` (the container). When the container has the `perspective`, the shape moves in the z direction fine. But, when the subcontainer (the parent) has something in the `transform`, other than `unset`, the `translateZ()` from the shape is fully ignored. Of course, applying `perspective` to the direct parent makes the `translateZ()` in the shape work, but I wanted to understand what in the parent `transform` blocks the `perspective` to be seen by the shape:

Below works:

```
.container{
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.subcontainer{
  transform: unset;     // <- or if this is not present at all
}

.shape{
  transform: translateZ(300px);
}
```

Below doesn't work:

```
.container{
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.subcontainer{
  transform: scale(1.001);
}

.shape{
  transform: translateZ(300px);    // <- this is fully ignored
}
```

Here is [this example](https://codepen.io/adriano-pinaffo/pen/YzGQBbQ) in codepen.

EDIT:
In many docs I read that `perspective` must be a property set in the parent element. But [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleZ()) seems to show that it can in fact be set in the intended element itself, inside the `transform` rule. So, is `perspective: 500px` in the parent equivalent to `transform: perspective(500px)` in the child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the specification:](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#transformed-element-hierarchies)

> By default, **transformed elements** do **not create a 3D rendering context** and create a flattened representation of their content. However, since it is useful to construct hierarchies of transformed objects that share a common 3-dimensional space, this flattening behavior may be overridden by specifying a value of `preserve-3d` for the `transform-style` property. **This allows descendants of the transformed element to share the same 3D rendering context**.

So simply add `transform-style:preserve-3d` to the subcontainer element and the perspective of the grand-parent will be respected:

```css
.container{
  background: #f4f7be;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.subcontainer{
  background: #baf7f6;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scale(1.001);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

.shape{
  background: #555;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  transform: translateZ(300px);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="subcontainer">
      <div class="shape"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

---

> So, is perspective: 500px in the parent equivalent to transform: perspective(500px) in the child?

Not exactly equivalent because you need to consider other factors like the parent dimension, transform-origin, perspective-origin, etc

A trivial example:

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="perspective:100px;">
  <div style="transform:translateZ(10px);"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div style="transform:perspective(100px) translateZ(10px);"></div>
</div>
```

The difference is due to the origin. In the first case, the perspective will use the center of the parent as origin (because `perspective-origin` is center by default). In the second case, the center of the element will be used as origin (because `transform-origin` is center by default)

Related questions for more detail and examples:

[perspective and translateZ moves diagonally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54987891/8620333)

[Why perspective isn't giving the same result when some styles are updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63026056/8620333)

[CSS 3d transform doesn't work if perspective is set in the end of property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51891329/8620333)

Comment: so, for the first one, isn't it weird that when the parent element has no transform specified the "3D features are preserved" even if you don't specify anything in the transform-style of the parent?

Comment: @Adriano_Pinaffo it's not that weird because transform-style doesn't really control the 3D feature. The 3D is controled by perspective (you can find the full detail here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#3d-transform-rendering) BUT in some cases the 3D context is disabled for some hierarchy (maybe for perf issue) and you have the ability to activate it again using transform-style. Like in your case where an element having transform will not propagate the 3D rendring context to its child element.