# How can I measure the width and height of a rotated element on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

There is a bug with my design interface where the width and height of my selected div are false when rotated.

Here's a schema of what I have and another one of what I want.

[image]

I want to find the formula using Javascript, how can I possibly write it ?

*PS : I already have the angle, the width and the height of the first schema, no need to calculate it again.*

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18356970/446594)

Comment: @DarkBee http://jsfiddle.net/x5Qgx/ this is the JSFiddle suggested, unfortunately it doesn't work, you'll see that when you rotate in at 0 deg, the height and the width with changes, (it should always stay to 200).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Width` and `height` are  not changing, when `rotate` the element .its also the same see the snippet .get the `value` via dom use with

1. [`offsetWidth`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetwidth.asp)
2. [`offsetHeight`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetwidth.asp)

```js
var rot =document.getElementById("rot");
console.log(rot.offsetWidth,rot.offsetHeight)
```

```css
#rot{
width:100px;
height:40px;
background-color:pink;
transform:rotate(30deg)
}
```

```html
<div id="rot"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is equations you need, Then here you go.

```
w-y*sin(theta) = x*cos(theta)
h-y*cos(theta) = x*sin(theta)
```

Where,

```
w = given width
h = given height
x = width you need
y = height you need
theta = angle
```

A little trigonometry goes a long way.

Solving this simultaneous equation gives me -

```
2x = (w+h)/(cos(theta)+sin(theta)) + (w-h)/(cos(theta)-sin(theta))
2y = (w+h)/(cos(theta)+sin(theta)) - (w-h)/(cos(theta)-sin(theta))
```

Feel free to convert to Math functions.