# How to get the real width and height of element after rotating it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how can i get the original dimensions of a element after rotating it, when i use `transform: rotate()` and try to get the dimensions after rotate using `element.getBoundingClientRect()` it returns a different **width** and **heigh**, is it possible to get the real dimensions after rotating a element?

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById('one')
let div2 = document.getElementById('two')

// Here the width and height is 50 and 80
console.log(div1.getBoundingClientRect())

// Here because i used transform rotate the width is 86 and height 94
console.log(div2.getBoundingClientRect())
```

```css
div#one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}

div#two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<br/>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Comment: you can just save the height of your element before rotation and use that as a ref.

Comment: `getComputedStyle(element)["height"]` and `getComputedStyle(element)["width"]` is a potential option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I measure the width and height of a rotated element on Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322096/how-can-i-measure-the-width-and-height-of-a-rotated-element-on-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to clone the second div with `cloneNode` and then remove the `tranform` style to get it's original dimensions, please see snippet.

```js
    let div1 = document.getElementById('one');
    let div2 = document.getElementById('two');
    //clone the rotated div and then remove the transform style
    //this will give you it's original dimensions
    let div3 = div2.cloneNode(false);
    div3.style.transform = "none";
    //hide the clone
    div3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    //append to the body
    document.body.append(div3);
    
    console.log(div3.getBoundingClientRect());
    
    //remove clone from the DOM
    div3.remove();
    // Here the width and height is 50 and 80
    console.log(div1.getBoundingClientRect());

    // Here because i used transform rotate the width is 86 and height 94
    console.log(div2.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
div#one {
      width: 50px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: red;
    }

    div#two {
      width: 50px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: red;
      transform: rotate(35deg);
    }
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="two"></div>
```

Comment: This gives me a width and height of 0, for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, i tested here and your idea worked perfectly, i didn't realized that. But your code isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`. This is likely more efficient than cloning and modifying the element.

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById('one')
let div2 = document.getElementById('two')

// Here the width and height is 50 and 80
console.log(div1.getBoundingClientRect())

// Here because i used transform rotate the width is 86 and height 94
console.log(div2.getBoundingClientRect())

console.log(div2.offsetWidth);
console.log(div2.offsetHeight);
```

```css
div#one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}

div#two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<br/>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works too but working with `getBoundingClientRect` is better sometimes because it returns the real dimensions when the element is resized, so this is why i'm not using `offsetWidth` or `clientWidth`

Comment: @Nisala I gave you an upvote. I updated my answer and it appears to work but uses more resources.

Comment: What i mean is if you use `transform: scale(1.3)` in an element, the difference is that if you use `getBoundingClientRect().width` it will return the real dimensions, but if you use `offset.width` it will return the dimensions without considering the `transform: scale()` property