# Creating a resizable/draggable/rotate view in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, coordinates

I've been trying to create something like this in Javascript:

[image]

As you can see, the container can be dragged, rotated and resized. Most of the things work fine but the resizing of container when it is rotated produce weird output.

I expect this to happen:

[image]

Instead I get this:

[image]

Here's the full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/c0krownz/

or,

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var boxWrapper = document.getElementById("box-wrapper");

var initX, initY, mousePressX, mousePressY, initW, initH, initRotate;

function repositionElement(x, y) {
    boxWrapper.style.left = x;
    boxWrapper.style.top = y;
}

function resize(w, h) {
    box.style.width = w + 'px';
    box.style.height = h + 'px';
    boxWrapper.style.width = w;
    boxWrapper.style.height = h;
}


function getCurrentRotation(el) {
    var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    var tm = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("transform")
    "none";
    if (tm != "none") {
        var values = tm.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[1], values[0]) * (180 / Math.PI));
        return (angle < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle);
    }
    return 0;
}

function rotateBox(deg) {
    boxWrapper.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
}

// drag support
boxWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.target.className.indexOf("dot") > -1) {
        return;
    }

    initX = this.offsetLeft;
    initY = this.offsetTop;
    mousePressX = event.clientX;
    mousePressY = event.clientY;


    function eventMoveHandler(event) {
        repositionElement(initX + (event.clientX - mousePressX) + 'px',
            initY + (event.clientY - mousePressY) + 'px');
    }

    boxWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        boxWrapper.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
    }, false);

}, false);
// done drag support

// handle resize
var rightMid = document.getElementById("right-mid");
var leftMid = document.getElementById("left-mid");
var topMid = document.getElementById("top-mid");
var bottomMid = document.getElementById("bottom-mid");

var leftTop = document.getElementById("left-top");
var rightTop = document.getElementById("right-top");
var rightBottom = document.getElementById("right-bottom");
var leftBottom = document.getElementById("left-bottom");

function resizeHandler(event, left = false, top = false, xResize = false, yResize = false) {
    initX = boxWrapper.offsetLeft;
    initY = boxWrapper.offsetTop;
    mousePressX = event.clientX;
    mousePressY = event.clientY;

    initW = box.offsetWidth;
    initH = box.offsetHeight;

    initRotate = getCurrentRotation(boxWrapper);

    function eventMoveHandler(event) {
        var wDiff = event.clientX - mousePressX;
        var hDiff = event.clientY - mousePressY;

        var newW = initW, newH = initH, newX = initX, newY = initY;

        if (xResize) {
            if (left) {
                newW = initW - wDiff;
                newX = initX + wDiff;
            } else {
                newW = initW + wDiff;
            }
        }

        if (yResize) {
            if (top) {
                newH = initH - hDiff;
                newY = initY + hDiff;
            } else {
                newH = initH + hDiff;
            }
        }

        resize(newW, newH);
        repositionElement(newX, newY);
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
    }, false);
}


rightMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, false, true, false));
leftMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, true, false, true, false));
topMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, true, false, true));
bottomMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, false, false, true));
leftTop.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, true, true, true, true));
rightTop.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, true, true, true));
rightBottom.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, false, true, true));
leftBottom.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, true, false, true, true));

// handle rotation
var rotate = document.getElementById("rotate");
rotate.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    // if (event.target.className.indexOf("dot") > -1) {
    //     return;
    // }

    initX = this.offsetLeft;
    initY = this.offsetTop;
    mousePressX = event.clientX;
    mousePressY = event.clientY;


    var arrow = document.querySelector("#box");
    var arrowRects = arrow.getBoundingClientRect();
    var arrowX = arrowRects.left + arrowRects.width / 2;
    var arrowY = arrowRects.top + arrowRects.height / 2;

    function eventMoveHandler(event) {
        var angle = Math.atan2(event.clientY - arrowY, event.clientX - arrowX) + Math.PI / 2;
        rotateBox(angle * 180 / Math.PI);
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
    }, false);

}, false);



resize(300, 200);
repositionElement(100, 100);
```

```css
.box {
    background-color: #00BCD4;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
}

.box-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center center;
    user-select: none;
}

.dot {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #1E88E5;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    user-select: none;
}

.dot:hover {
    background-color: #0D47A1;
}

.dot.left-top {
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    /* cursor: nw-resize; */
}

.dot.left-bottom {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    /* cursor: sw-resize; */
}

.dot.right-top {
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    /* cursor: ne-resize; */
}

.dot.right-bottom {
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    /* cursor: se-resize; */
}

.dot.top-mid {
    top: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: n-resize; */
}

.dot.left-mid {
    left: -5px;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: w-resize; */
}

.dot.right-mid {
    right: -5px;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: e-resize; */
}

.dot.bottom-mid {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: s-resize; */
}

.dot.rotate {
    top: -30px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    cursor: url('https://findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/16/rotate_ccw.png'), auto;
}

.rotate-link {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #1E88E5;
    top: -20px;
    left: calc(50% + 0.5px);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper" id="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box" id="box">
        <div class="dot rotate" id="rotate"></div>
        <div class="dot left-top" id="left-top"></div>
        <div class="dot left-bottom" id="left-bottom"></div>
        <div class="dot top-mid" id="top-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot bottom-mid" id="bottom-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot left-mid" id="left-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot right-mid" id="right-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot right-bottom" id="right-bottom"></div>
        <div class="dot right-top" id="right-top"></div>
        <div class="rotate-link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/c0krownz/) it is on jsfiddle.

Comment: One bug is that there is a missing  + 'px' in repositionElement method for the  boxWrapper.style.left &  boxWrapper.style.top (lines 7+8 in jsfiddle). You can also see that without it, the box won't change it's inital place. Once you changed there, don't forget to remove the + 'px' in lines 52 + 53 in jsfiddle. Also add + 'px' in lines 14 + 15 in jsfiddle as you did in lines 12 + 13

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### Assigning CSS with Units

When you set `element.style.top` and `element.style.left`, you need to specify units (usually pixels, `px`, when doing this type of element transformation). In your case, you only set the units in the `eventMoveHandler`, which makes it only work in the move handler.

In the below snippet I've changed it to automatically add `px` to `repositionElement`, and removed the units from `eventMoveHandler`. I also removed `boxWrapper.style.width = w;` and `boxWrapper.style.height = h;` in `resize`, as they didn't have units, and it was unclear where the `boxWrapper` dimensions were used.

#### Reassigning Coordinates

For me, it was easier to think about this problem in terms of the center of the box. Your original code uses the prerotated top left corner to keep track of position, which becomes hard to imagine on the rotated rectangle. The center, on the other hand, is always the center. To use the center, I added/changed this css:

```
.box {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box-wrapper {
    transform-origin: top left; /* changed from `center center` */
}
```

It also simplifies the code a bit in `resizeHandler`/`eventMoveHandler`:

```
if (xResize) {
    if (left) {
        newW = initW - wDiff;
    } else {
        newW = initW + wDiff;
    }
    newX += 0.5 * wDiff;
}
if (yResize) {
    if (top) {
        newH = initH - hDiff;
    } else {
        newH = initH + hDiff;
    }
    newY += 0.5 * hDiff;
}
```

Now `box-wrapper`'s `style.top` and `style.left` coordinates are actually at the center of the `box`. If this coordinate system doesn't work, we can revisit it.

#### Taking Rotation Into Account When Resizing

From here, we need to take into account the rotation of the box when resizing it. For example, when the box is rotated 90 degrees, all of the x changes become y changes. To transform them, you can use `Math.cos` and `Math.sin`

```
var initRadians = initRotate * Math.PI / 180;
var cosFraction = Math.cos(initRadians);
var sinFraction = Math.sin(initRadians);
//...
var wDiff = (event.clientX - mousePressX);
var hDiff = (event.clientY - mousePressY);
var rotatedWDiff = cosFraction * wDiff + sinFraction * hDiff;
var rotatedHDiff = cosFraction * hDiff - sinFraction * wDiff;
//...
if (xResize) {
    if (left) {
        newW = initW - rotatedWDiff;
    } else {
        newW = initW + rotatedWDiff;
    }
    //...
}
if (yResize) {
    if (top) {
        newH = initH - rotatedHDiff;
    } else {
        newH = initH + rotatedHDiff;
    }
    //...
}
```

Also, when you correct your position, you should be using the sin and cos fractions too, because the position set by `style.top` and `style.left` does not normally take rotation into account:

```
if (xResize) {
   //...
   newX += 0.5 * rotatedWDiff * cosFraction;
   newY += 0.5 * rotatedWDiff * sinFraction;
}
if (yResize) {
   //...
   newX -= 0.5 * rotatedHDiff * sinFraction;
   newY += 0.5 * rotatedHDiff * cosFraction;
}
```

#### Applying a Minimum Width and Height

As pointed out in the comments, the behavior is strange when the dragged edge or corner goes beyond the anchored edges. In this case, you'd expect either the box to be flipped, or the box to stop being resized. I'll use a minimum width and height here, since the implementation seems to be simpler.

```
const minWidth = 40;
const minHeight = 40;
//...
if (xResize) {
    if (left) {
        newW = initW - rotatedWDiff;
        if (newW < minWidth) {
          newW = minWidth;
          rotatedWDiff = initW - minWidth;
        }
    } else {
        newW = initW + rotatedWDiff;
        if (newW < minWidth) {
          newW = minWidth;
          rotatedWDiff = minWidth - initW;
        }
    }
    //..
}
if (yResize) {
    if (top) {
        newH = initH - rotatedHDiff;
        if (newH < minHeight) {
          newH = minHeight;
          rotatedHDiff = initH - minHeight;
        }
    } else {
        newH = initH + rotatedHDiff;
        if (newH < minHeight) {
          newH = minHeight;
          rotatedHDiff = minHeight - initH;
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

***Aside: Removing Event Listeners***

Unrelated to the heart of the matter is removing event listeners. Ironically, the code to remove your event listener, leaves up an event listener in `mouseup`:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
}, false);
```

This isn't that big of a problem, as the function doesn't do too much if run repeatedly, and the closures don't really take up that much memory. But to really clean it up, we can change it to something like:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function eventEndHandler() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', eventEndHandler, false);
}, false);
```

### The Result

All together, it looks like:

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var boxWrapper = document.getElementById("box-wrapper");
const minWidth = 40;
const minHeight = 40;


var initX, initY, mousePressX, mousePressY, initW, initH, initRotate;

function repositionElement(x, y) {
    boxWrapper.style.left = x + 'px';
    boxWrapper.style.top = y + 'px';
}

function resize(w, h) {
    box.style.width = w + 'px';
    box.style.height = h + 'px';
}


function getCurrentRotation(el) {
    var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    var tm = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("transform")
    "none";
    if (tm != "none") {
        var values = tm.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[1], values[0]) * (180 / Math.PI));
        return (angle < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle);
    }
    return 0;
}

function rotateBox(deg) {
    boxWrapper.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
}

// drag support
boxWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.target.className.indexOf("dot") > -1) {
        return;
    }

    initX = this.offsetLeft;
    initY = this.offsetTop;
    mousePressX = event.clientX;
    mousePressY = event.clientY;


    function eventMoveHandler(event) {
        repositionElement(initX + (event.clientX - mousePressX),
            initY + (event.clientY - mousePressY));
    }

    boxWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function eventEndHandler() {
        boxWrapper.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', eventEndHandler);
    }, false);

}, false);
// done drag support

// handle resize
var rightMid = document.getElementById("right-mid");
var leftMid = document.getElementById("left-mid");
var topMid = document.getElementById("top-mid");
var bottomMid = document.getElementById("bottom-mid");

var leftTop = document.getElementById("left-top");
var rightTop = document.getElementById("right-top");
var rightBottom = document.getElementById("right-bottom");
var leftBottom = document.getElementById("left-bottom");

function resizeHandler(event, left = false, top = false, xResize = false, yResize = false) {
    initX = boxWrapper.offsetLeft;
    initY = boxWrapper.offsetTop;
    mousePressX = event.clientX;
    mousePressY = event.clientY;

    initW = box.offsetWidth;
    initH = box.offsetHeight;

    initRotate = getCurrentRotation(boxWrapper);
    var initRadians = initRotate * Math.PI / 180;
    var cosFraction = Math.cos(initRadians);
    var sinFraction = Math.sin(initRadians);
    function eventMoveHandler(event) {
        var wDiff = (event.clientX - mousePressX);
        var hDiff = (event.clientY - mousePressY);
        var rotatedWDiff = cosFraction * wDiff + sinFraction * hDiff;
        var rotatedHDiff = cosFraction * hDiff - sinFraction * wDiff;

        var newW = initW, newH = initH, newX = initX, newY = initY;

        if (xResize) {
            if (left) {
                newW = initW - rotatedWDiff;
                if (newW < minWidth) {
                  newW = minWidth;
                  rotatedWDiff = initW - minWidth;
                }
            } else {
                newW = initW + rotatedWDiff;
                if (newW < minWidth) {
                  newW = minWidth;
                  rotatedWDiff = minWidth - initW;
                }
            }
            newX += 0.5 * rotatedWDiff * cosFraction;
            newY += 0.5 * rotatedWDiff * sinFraction;
        }

        if (yResize) {
            if (top) {
                newH = initH - rotatedHDiff;
                if (newH < minHeight) {
                  newH = minHeight;
                  rotatedHDiff = initH - minHeight;
                }
            } else {
                newH = initH + rotatedHDiff;
                if (newH < minHeight) {
                  newH = minHeight;
                  rotatedHDiff = minHeight - initH;
                }
            }
            newX -= 0.5 * rotatedHDiff * sinFraction;
            newY += 0.5 * rotatedHDiff * cosFraction;
        }

        resize(newW, newH);
        repositionElement(newX, newY);
    }


    window.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function eventEndHandler() {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', eventEndHandler);
    }, false);
}


rightMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, false, true, false));
leftMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, true, false, true, false));
topMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, true, false, true));
bottomMid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, false, false, true));
leftTop.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, true, true, true, true));
rightTop.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, true, true, true));
rightBottom.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, false, false, true, true));
leftBottom.addEventListener('mousedown', e => resizeHandler(e, true, false, true, true));

// handle rotation
var rotate = document.getElementById("rotate");
rotate.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    // if (event.target.className.indexOf("dot") > -1) {
    //     return;
    // }

    initX = this.offsetLeft;
    initY = this.offsetTop;
    mousePressX = event.clientX;
    mousePressY = event.clientY;


    var arrow = document.querySelector("#box");
    var arrowRects = arrow.getBoundingClientRect();
    var arrowX = arrowRects.left + arrowRects.width / 2;
    var arrowY = arrowRects.top + arrowRects.height / 2;

    function eventMoveHandler(event) {
        var angle = Math.atan2(event.clientY - arrowY, event.clientX - arrowX) + Math.PI / 2;
        rotateBox(angle * 180 / Math.PI);
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function eventEndHandler() {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMoveHandler, false);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', eventEndHandler);
    }, false);
}, false);

resize(300, 200);
repositionElement(200, 200);
```

```css
.box {
    background-color: #00BCD4;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: top left;
    user-select: none;
}

.dot {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #1E88E5;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    user-select: none;
}

.dot:hover {
    background-color: #0D47A1;
}

.dot.left-top {
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    /* cursor: nw-resize; */
}

.dot.left-bottom {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    /* cursor: sw-resize; */
}

.dot.right-top {
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    /* cursor: ne-resize; */
}

.dot.right-bottom {
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    /* cursor: se-resize; */
}

.dot.top-mid {
    top: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: n-resize; */
}

.dot.left-mid {
    left: -5px;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: w-resize; */
}

.dot.right-mid {
    right: -5px;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: e-resize; */
}

.dot.bottom-mid {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    /* cursor: s-resize; */
}

.dot.rotate {
    top: -30px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    cursor: url('https://findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/16/rotate_ccw.png'), auto;
}

.rotate-link {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #1E88E5;
    top: -20px;
    left: calc(50% + 0.5px);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper" id="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box" id="box">
        <div class="dot rotate" id="rotate"></div>
        <div class="dot left-top" id="left-top"></div>
        <div class="dot left-bottom" id="left-bottom"></div>
        <div class="dot top-mid" id="top-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot bottom-mid" id="bottom-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot left-mid" id="left-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot right-mid" id="right-mid"></div>
        <div class="dot right-bottom" id="right-bottom"></div>
        <div class="dot right-top" id="right-top"></div>
        <div class="rotate-link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this. Also with the explanations, it helped me understand a lot of things regarding transformation.

Comment: Glad that it helps! Let me know if you have any additional questions

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I'll award you the bounty in 10 hours. Stackoverflow doesn't let me right now

Comment: I think there is still an issue that the element is draggable while you resize it. try to resize and drag it away, and you can see that the element moves. (happens with/without rotation). it should stay in place when resizing.

Comment: Great answer! May I ask how you determined what the correction for the position needed to be? I found the other trigonometry [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773788/rectangle-rotation-and-scale), but was less clear on how to adjust for these positioning variations as the rotated rectangle became more oblique.

Comment: @bentz123, Which browser are you using? I'm not seeing it in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: @sbgib, Mercifully, the math is pretty simple when calculating from the center of the box. Without the position correction, resizing makes the box look like it's stretching around the center. For the opposite side/corner to appear anchored, the center has to move half the distance in the direction of the stretch. And since the box may be rotated, the stretch should be multipled by the cosine and sine of the rotation angle to get the x and y position changes. I suspect the math gets more complicated when calculating from the prerotated top-left corner, but I haven't really worked it out.

Comment: @Steve thank you! One option which seemed quite promising to deal with the complexity if using the prerotated top-left corner is to use the dimensions returned by [getBoundingClientRect()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18356970) to then offset the position as the box is resized. Nevertheless, a purely mathematical solution is cleaner and more universally applicable.

Comment: Chrome as well, try to resize and drag away

Comment: @sbgib, be careful with `getBoundingClientRect` with rotations... it gives an unrotated bounding box for the rotated object. The bounding box will be bigger or at least as big as the object itself, and its top left corner is usually different than the top-left corners for both the unrotated or rotated object. It's useful for certain applications, but I'd have a hard time finding a use for it here.

Comment: @bentz123, I'm not seeing or understanding the issue as described, could you make a clip of this in action?

Comment: @Steve, I took a clip of your answer and dipen-shah to compare https://streamable.com/utz5h9. you can see that the element start to float around, whereas it should stay in place when resizing

Comment: @bentz123, thanks for the clip, it's clarifying! It looks like the issue arises when the stretched edge/corner passes the anchored edges/corners-- i.e. the width/height becomes negative. I've updated my answer to explore this case a bit more and to use a minimum width and height.

Comment: @Steve agreed! That was a possible solution where the box rotates within a static wrapper instead.

Comment: Nice and works great! One improvement could be to have sizer cursors on every circle.

Comment: Waterfox 56: `boxWrapper is null` and Chrome 86: `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.

Comment: Hi @John, I'm not getting those errors. Just checking-- are you getting those errors in Stack Overflow, or on a separately made page?

Comment: @John, is your JavaScript before the elements are defined? Generally the way StackOverflow Snippets work are that the *HTML elements* are defined before the JavaScript is run

Comment: @Steve I code strictly so I do not dump `script` elements like a hot mess in to the bottom of the `body` element. Lazy programming is costly in terms of maintenance and often reflects a lack of true understanding of the code one is working with.

Comment: @John, we can debate what is better practice, but if you use a different setup then the Stack Overflow convention, you should well be aware of how to adapt the code to meet your standards and hardly be surprised if it doesn't run out of the box. Since you have strong opinions and appear to be a fairly experienced web developer, you really should know that you should wrap any JavaScript code that depends on selecting DOM nodes in some sort of DOM listener (`window.onload` / `document.body.onload` are common) if you're running it before the `body`.

Comment: @Steve How can I maintain the aspect ratio of box?

Comment: @RadicalEdward, a straightforward way would be to calculate a scale based off of the larger (or smaller) of `newH / initH` and `newW / initW`, and then change `resize(newW, newH)` to `resize(initW * scale, initH * scale)`. You can see a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731922).

Comment: @RadicalEdward, come to think of it, this is complicated because the position is also adjusted based off of the new height and width. In this case, you'd want to separate the calculations of `newH` and `newW` first, set them based on constrained aspect ratio values, then adjust `newX` and `newY` based off of that. If this is confusing, feel feel to open this as another question and link me to it.

Comment: @Steve  I could make it work at least for square box but its not robust. If there is easier way for retaining square shape, it would be great. my solution is quite hacky for now.
You are right, I struggled a lot for repositioning element.

Comment: @RadicalEdward, I don't think a square aspect ratio would make things much easier (assuming you can still rotate and use various anchored resizing). I tried this out; my implementation isn't too complicated, but longer than what fits in a comment and outside the scope of this answer. It should probably be discussed in a new question (just be as detailed as possible for your use case, and reply with a link)

Comment: @Steve, Here is question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328161/how-to-retain-aspect-ratio-of-resizable-draggable-element
Probably I am not up to rule of commenting here.

Comment: @Steve hello. is it possible to make this on flutter? i tried to implement in flutter but still need computation to detect new position when resizing. I really appreciate it if you want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885487/flutter-how-to-keep-offset-when-resize-widget-after-rotated

Comment: Thank you! This code is going to directly benefit some children with accessibility challenges

Answer (score 11):

While it is a good exercise to understand basics of shape transformation, you don't have to do it fortunately as this is already a solved problem. I believe Steve already added fix for issue in your existing code but I would recommend to use existing solution such as [konvajs](https://konvajs.org/) as opposed to reinventing the wheel.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height,
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 60,
  y: 60,
  width: 100,
  height: 90,
  fill: 'red',
  name: 'rect',
  draggable: true,
});
layer.add(rect1);

var tr = new Konva.Transformer();
layer.add(tr);
tr.nodes([rect1]);
layer.draw();
```

```css
#container {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@7.1.4/konva.min.js"></script>
<h1>Resizable shape</h1>
<div id="container"></div>
```