# Resizing and Rotating multiple selected elements / objects

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, resize, multi-select

I'm working on a project where I need to implement resizing and rotating functionality for multiple elements. Each element can be selected individually, and when multiple elements are selected, resizing should be done collectively, exactly like how Figma's resize and rotate does it.

I have found this solution works well for resizing rotated single element: [Resizing rotated elements while maintaining aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328161/how-to-fix-aspect-ratio-of-resizable-draggable-element)

[image]

Now I need to find out how to resize and rotate multiple selected elements. But I'm not sure where to start, can someone point me in the right direction? Even only the math theories/concepts that might help, would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

(P.S.) Using a library is out of my options so I need to do this manually