# Creating a resizable/rotate view in vue

Tags: vue.js

The same problem as the following url occurs in vue.js. The difference is that if the solution changed the reference point of the position, I would like to know how not to change the reference point.

[Creating a resizable/draggable/rotate view in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64690514/creating-a-resizable-draggable-rotate-view-in-javascript)

```
<template>
  <div
    class="z-drr-container"
    @mousedown.left.stop="elmDown"
    :style="style"
    :class="{
      'z-draggable': draggable,
      'z-resizable': resizable,
      'z-rotatable': rotatable,
      'z-active': enabled,
      'z-dragging': dragging,
      'z-resizing': resizing,
      'z-rotating': rotating
    }">
    <slot/>
    <div
      v-if="rotatable"
      class="z-rotateable-handle"
      :style="{ display: enabled ? 'block' : 'none'}"
      @mousedown.stop.prevent="rotating = true"/>
    <template v-if="resizable">
      <div
        v-for="handle in handles" :key="handle"
        class="z-resizeable-handle"
        :class="'z-handle-' + handle"
        :style="{ display: enabled ? 'block' : 'none'}"
        @mousedown.stop.prevent="handleResizeStart(handle, $event)"/>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { HANDLER_EXCLUDE_CLASS_LIST } from '@/designer/designer-constant';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'ComponentHandler',
  props: {
    active: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    draggable: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    resizable: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    rotatable: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    locked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    w: {
      type: Number, default: 200,
      validator (val) {
        return val > 0;
      }
    },
    h: {
      type: Number, default: 200,
      validator (val) {
        return val > 0;
      }
    },
    minw: {
      type: Number, default: 1,
      validator (val) {
        return val > 0;
      }
    },
    minh: {
      type: Number, default: 1,
      validator (val) {
        return val > 0;
      }
    },
    angle: {
      type: Number, default: 0,
      validator (val) {
        return typeof val === 'number';
      }
    },
    x: {
      type: Number, default: 0,
      validator (val) {
        return typeof val === 'number';
      }
    },
    y: {
      type: Number, default: 0,
      validator (val) {
        return typeof val === 'number';
      }
    },
    handles: {
      type: Array,
      default () {
        return ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'nw', 'ne', 'se', 'sw'];
      }
    },
    axis: {
      type: String, default: 'both',
      validator (val) {
        return ['x', 'y', 'both'].indexOf(val) !== -1;
      }
    },
    grid: {
      type: Array,
      default () {
        return [1, 1];
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      top: this.y,
      left: this.x,
      width: this.w,
      height: this.h,
      rotateAngle: this.angle,
      resizing: false,
      dragging: false,
      rotating: false,
      handle: null,

      eleDownX: 0,
      eleDownY: 0,

      mouseOffX: 0,
      mouseOffY: 0,
      lastMouseX: 0,
      lastMouseY: 0,
      elmX: 0,
      elmY: 0,
      elmW: 0,
      elmH: 0
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('vuex_view', ['getViewScale']),
    style () {
      return {
        top: this.top + 'px',
        left: this.left + 'px',
        width: this.width + 'px',
        height: this.height + 'px',
        transform: 'rotate(' + this.rotateAngle + 'deg)'
      };
    },
    enabled () {
      return this.active;
    },
    isChangedPosition () {
      return this.x !== this.left || this.y !== this.top;
    },
    viewScale () {
      return this.getViewScale;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    x: {
      handler: function (x) {
        this.left = x;
        this.elmX = x;
      }, immediate: true
    },
    y: {
      handler: function (y) {
        this.top = y;
        this.elmY = y;
      }, immediate: true
    },
    w: {
      handler: function (w) {
        this.width = w;
        this.elmW = w;
      }, immediate: true
    },
    h: {
      handler: function (h) {
        this.height = h;
        this.elmH = h;
      }, immediate: true
    },
    angle: {
      handler: function (angle) {
        this.rotateAngle = angle;
      }, immediate: true
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMove, true);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleUp, true);

    this.reviewDimensions();
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMove, true);
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleUp, true);
  },
  methods: {
    reviewDimensions () {
      if (this.minw > this.w) {
        this.width = this.minw;
      }

      if (this.minh > this.h) {
        this.height = this.minh;
      }
    },
    elmDown (e) {
      if (this.hasHandlerExclude(e)) return;

      this.reviewDimensions();

      if (this.draggable) {
        this.dragging = true;
      }
      else {
        this.eleDownX = this.getMouseX(e);
        this.eleDownY = this.getMouseY(e);
      }
    },
    hasHandlerExclude (e) {
      for (const className of HANDLER_EXCLUDE_CLASS_LIST) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains(className)) return true;
      }
      return false;
    },

    handleResizeStart (handle, e) {
      this.handle = handle;

      if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
      if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

      this.resizing = true;
    },
    getOrigin () {
      const rect = this.$el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        x: (rect.left + rect.right) / 2,
        y: (rect.bottom + rect.top) / 2
      };
    },
    getMouseX (e) {
      return e.pageX || e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    },
    getMouseY (e) {
      return e.pageY || e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    },
    handleMove (e) {
      const lastMouseX = this.lastMouseX;
      const lastMouseY = this.lastMouseY;

      const mouseX = this.getMouseX(e);
      const mouseY = this.getMouseY(e);

      let diffX = (mouseX - this.lastMouseX + this.mouseOffX) / this.viewScale;
      let diffY = (mouseY - this.lastMouseY + this.mouseOffY) / this.viewScale;

      this.mouseOffX = this.mouseOffY = 0;

      this.lastMouseX = mouseX;
      this.lastMouseY = mouseY;

      const dX = diffX;
      const dY = diffY;

      if (this.resizing) {
        if (this.handle.indexOf('n') >= 0) {
          if (this.elmH - dY < this.minh) {
            diffY = this.elmH - this.minh;
          }
          else if (this.elmY + dY < 0) {
            diffY = -this.elmY;
          }
          this.mouseOffY = dY - diffY;
          this.elmY += diffY;
          this.elmH -= diffY;
        }

        if (this.handle.indexOf('s') >= 0) {
          if (this.elmH + dY < this.minh) {
            diffY = this.minh - this.elmH;
          }
          this.mouseOffY = dY - diffY;
          this.elmH += diffY;
        }

        if (this.handle.indexOf('w') >= 0) {
          if (this.elmW - dX < this.minw) {
            diffX = this.elmW - this.minw;
          }
          else if (this.elmX + dX < 0) {
            diffX = -this.elmX;
          }
          this.mouseOffX = dX - diffX;
          this.elmX += diffX;
          this.elmW -= diffX;
        }

        if (this.handle.indexOf('e') >= 0) {
          if (this.elmW + dX < this.minw) {
            diffX = this.minw - this.elmW;
          }
          this.mouseOffX = dX - diffX;
          this.elmW += diffX;
        }

        this.left = (Math.round(this.elmX / this.grid[0]) * this.grid[0]);
        this.top = (Math.round(this.elmY / this.grid[1]) * this.grid[1]);

        this.width = (Math.round(this.elmW / this.grid[0]) * this.grid[0]);
        this.height = (Math.round(this.elmH / this.grid[1]) * this.grid[1]);

        this.$emit('resizing', this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);
      }
      else if (this.dragging) {
        this.elmX += diffX;
        this.elmY += diffY;

        if (this.axis === 'x' || this.axis === 'both') {
          this.left = (Math.round(this.elmX / this.grid[0]) * this.grid[0]);
        }
        if (this.axis === 'y' || this.axis === 'both') {
          this.top = (Math.round(this.elmY / this.grid[1]) * this.grid[1]);
        }

        this.$emit('dragging', this.left, this.top);
      }
      else if (this.rotating) {
        const origin = this.getOrigin();
        const lastAngle = Math.atan2(lastMouseY - origin.y, lastMouseX - origin.x);
        const currentAngle = Math.atan2(mouseY - origin.y, mouseX - origin.x);
        this.rotateAngle += Math.round((currentAngle - lastAngle) * 180 / Math.PI);
        this.$emit('rotating', this.rotateAngle);
      }
    },
    handleUp (e) {
      this.handle = null;
      if (this.resizing) {
        this.resizing = false;
        this.$emit('resizestop', this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);
      }
      if (this.dragging) {
        this.dragging = false;
        if (this.isChangedPosition) {
          this.$emit('dragstop', this.left, this.top);
        }
      } else if (this.eleDownX && this.eleDownY && this.locked) {
        const nowX = this.getMouseX(e);
        const nowY = this.getMouseY(e);
        const diffX = (nowX - this.eleDownX) / this.viewScale;
        const diffY = (nowY - this.eleDownY) / this.viewScale;

        if (diffX + diffY > 10) {
          this.$toasted.info('Component layout is locked.');
        }
        this.eleDownX = null;
        this.eleDownY = null;
      }

      if (this.rotating) {
        this.rotating = false;
        this.$emit('rotatestop', this.rotateAngle);
      }

      this.elmX = this.left;
      this.elmY = this.top;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
$main-color: #c82333;
$circle-size: 8px;
$calculated-size: -($circle-size * 0.5) - 1;
$calculated-size2: -($circle-size * 0.5);

.z-drr-container {
  position: absolute;

  *, *:before, *:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

.z-draggable:hover {
  cursor: move;
}

@mixin circle($bgc: #fff) {
  position: absolute;
  width: $circle-size;
  height: $circle-size;
  border: 1px solid $main-color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: $bgc;
}

.z-rotateable-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -25px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  margin-left: -.5px;
  background: url("../assets/images/rotate_01.png");
  cursor: url(../assets/mouserotate.png) 8 8, default;
}

.z-resizeable-handle {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.z-handle-nw,
.z-handle-ne,
.z-handle-sw,
.z-handle-se {
  @include circle;
}

.z-handle-nw {
  top: $calculated-size;
  left: $calculated-size;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}

.z-handle-ne {
  top: $calculated-size;
  right: $calculated-size;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}

.z-handle-sw {
  bottom: $calculated-size;
  left: $calculated-size;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}

.z-handle-se {
  bottom: $calculated-size;
  right: $calculated-size;
  cursor: se-resize;
}

.z-handle-n,
.z-handle-w,
.z-handle-e,
.z-handle-s {
  &:after {
    content: ' ';
    @include circle;
  }
}

.z-handle-n {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: $circle-size * 0.5;
  cursor: n-resize;

  &:after {
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: $calculated-size2;
  }
}

.z-handle-w {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: $circle-size * 0.5;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;

  &:after {
    top: 50%;
    right: 1px;
    margin-top: $calculated-size2;
  }
}

.z-handle-e {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: $circle-size * 0.5;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: e-resize;

  &:after {
    top: 50%;
    left: 1px;
    margin-top: $calculated-size2;
  }
}

.z-handle-s {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: $circle-size * 0.5;
  cursor: s-resize;

  &:after {
    top: 1px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: $calculated-size2;
  }
}

.z-active {
  // not working
  .z-resizeable-handle {
    z-index: 999;
  }
}
</style>
```