# In drag and rotate - containment is not working properly after rotating to vertical position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I'm using drag and rotate feature. Used this [plugin](https://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/jquery.ui.rotatable). Drag and rotate is working fine, but I need them with in a div. So I used 'Containment' property.

I used rectangular image,

**Problem:**

Horizontal position: No issues dragging is working fine with in div

**Vertical postion:** If I rotate the image to vertical position, then if I drag image, it is going out of parent div, also right side not able to drag to fully.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/4zwzu1f2/

**Html:**

```
<div id="draggable2" style="height:250px;width:500px;border-radius: 25px;background:grey;">
<div id="target2" style="width: 150px;height:10px; border: 1px solid #862dde; padding: 20px; padding-right: 40px;border-radius: 25px;">
  Drag and rotate me!
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {              
    $('#target2').rotatable(); $('#target2').draggable({containment:'parent'});
    });
</script>
```

**Plugin references:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.rotatable/1.0.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.rotatable/1.0.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [similar case to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013506/jquery-ui-draggable-element-looses-constraint-when-rotated)